# How to import existing form, from another to c#?

Tags: c#, import, controls

We are importing form, from existing project to our new project.
It works well in run time, but we can't see controls to modify them in design mode!
Do you know how what we do to see them?

Comment: is it winForms/WPF? details pls

Comment: What VS version do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it, when i add exist form to my project, in addition add formX.cs, also add another along files (designer and res). thats enough add formX.cs .